# OS X: Testing presence of an app from the command line with open

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to test whether Foo.app exists before I call:

```
$ open -a Foo.app bar
```

What search path does open use to look for Foo.app? I know it must include /Applications, which means it's not $PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd search it using [`mdfind`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) and then use the obtained path (if any) to open it:

```
    # use head to pick the first one, replace with your favorite algorithm
    FOOPATH=`mdfind "kMDItemContentTypeTree == 'com.apple.application-bundle'wc 
             && kMDItemDisplayName == 'Foo'wc" | head -n 1`
    if [ -d $FOOPATH ]; then
        open $FOOPATH
    else
        echo Opps
    fi
```